# Defining smooth manifolds without homeomorphisms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I would like to define smooth manifolds via atlases without homeomorphisms, by viewing it as a set (*not* a topological space) with maps and transition functions, by requiring the latter to be smooth maps (between sets in Euclidean space). This runs into a technical difficulty that it apriori does not rule out a non-Hausdorff pathological example like two lines glued along an open halfline. One way to handle this is to require the underlying set to be a Hausdorff topological space to begin with and the maps to be homeomorphisms. Is there a way of bypassing this intrusion of the continuous category? Of course one can just define the manifold a subset of Euclidean space which is locally a graph of a smooth function over a coordinate plane, but what if one wishes to stick to the atlas definition?

Do Carmo in his *Differential geometry of curves and surfaces* defines an abstract surface on page 425 using injective maps (rather than homeomorphisms).  On pages 438-439 he gives a similar definition of an $n$-dimensional differentiable manifold.  However this seems to be a mistake because it does not rule out the non-Hausdorff examples.  On page 439 in a remark he points out that "in some deeper theorem on manifolds it is necessary to impose some conditions on the natural topology of $M$" but does not explain what those conditions are.

Comment: I think do Carmo's differential geometry text uses sets instead of topological  spaces to introduce manifolds.  At some point, he adds the conditions of Hausdorff and second-countable in order to prove interesting theorems.  This is analogous to the situation in the algebraic geometry world, where schemes are not assumed to be separated, but varieties are.

Comment: Are you referring to his book on classical differential geometry or the textbook in Riemannian geometry? @S.Carnahan

Comment: In the book "Differential Geometry: Manifolds, Curves, and Surfaces" by Berger and Gostiaux, $C^p$ structures on $X$ are defined without referring to some fixed topology on $X$ (p. 54). However, this definition doesn't contains hausdorffness and second countability, they are added later once $X$ has been endowed with a canonical topology (p. 55). However, if I understand correctly it doesn't answer your question, you would like to get hausdorffness and second countability just by adding extra conditions on the charts, right ?

Comment: @ThomasRichard, I am wondering what the most economical way of doing this would be. Second countability is apparently no problem as one can just require the manifold to be path-connected, but to Hausdorff is causing a problem. Perhaps one can't avoid introducing it explicitly, *pace* do Carmo.

Comment: What about an approach saying "a set equipped with a Riemannian metric". It takes care of both separability and separatedness (and paracompactness), but the downside is you'd have to introduce several notions rather quickly in order to explain Riemannian metric to beginners. On the bright side, at least conceptually and morally and intuitively, people would expect to hear about distances in a geo-*metry* course :-)

Comment: @July, I like metrics but sometimes you have to do things in metricfree fashion, for example when you are working with vector fields.

Comment: You can add a condition on the transition maps requiring that for any path $\gamma$ in one chart and any transition map $t$, the partly defined composition $t\circ\gamma$ is proper (=the inverse image of compact is compact). This way you define something nice, but far more general than manifold; it includes orbifolds as well as quotients by locally free actions of Lie groups. $$\ $$ P.S. Why do you need it?

Comment: I think you can ensure second countability by requiring a countable family of charts and being Hausdorff by requiring that for each pair $x,y$ of points, you either find one chart containing both points or disjoint charts $U$ and $V$ with $x\in U$ and $y\in V$.